# ASP.NET Update Webpage when 'OnCheckedChanged'

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I'm trying to show controls on my webpage when someone clicks a NewUser checkbox but I cant get it working.

[Webpage Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyNVh.jpg)

This is my Login.aspx code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="NewUser" OnCheckedChanged="UpdateOptions" />
            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="NewUser">New User?</asp:Label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my Login.aspx.cs code:

```
//DM Create event to make controls visible if check box is selected
        public void UpdateOptions(object update, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(NewUser.Checked == true)
            {
                ConfirmEmailLabel.Visible = true;
                TextBox3.Visible = true;
                ConfirmPasswordLabel.Visible = true;
                TextBox4.Visible = true;
                Firstname.Visible = true;
                TextBox1.Visible = true;
                Lastname.Visible = true;
                TextBox2.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ConfirmEmailLabel.Visible = false;
                TextBox3.Visible = false;
                ConfirmPasswordLabel.Visible = false;
                TextBox4.Visible = false;
                Firstname.Visible = false;
                TextBox1.Visible = false;
                Lastname.Visible = false;
                TextBox2.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="NewUser" OnCheckedChanged="UpdateOptions" AutoPostBack="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set true AutoPostBack property of checkbox.

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" ID="NewUser" OnCheckedChanged="UpdateOptions" />
```